# Forgetting Mercurial file without propagating deletion to team

Tags: netbeans, mercurial

We have a file that was inadvertently and mistakenly added to our Mercurial repo.  The problem is this file is a Netbeans-specific file that Netbeans is constantly changing on everyone's local workspace.  So everytime they pull, Mercurial thinks they have modified local changes and won't allow them to merge without shelving that file.

How can we tell Mercurial to either remove or forget this file without propagating deletion of the file to the entire team.  Every time we've used hg forget or hg remove, the next time you pull from the repo, it deletes the file from your local workspace.

What are we missing?  Is there an easy way to do this without backing up the file, pulling, then replacing it after Mercurial deletes it?

Comment: is this cmd line? exactly what ccommands are you running to hg forget, hg pull and hg update?

Comment: I did it both cmd line and in TortoiseHg.  I am attempting it from the central shared repo my team is using.  The documentation is correct in that it doesn't remove it from the working directory of the shared repo.  However, when everyone on the team then pulls, it removes it from theirs.  Seems a bit strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this does not exist in Mercurial.

See [Issue 2212](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue2212).

Answer (score 0):

You could always write an extension that does what you want... ;)

Easy? no... but maybe not too much work (2-4 hours?) and useful for everyone.

Comment: Agreed.  I'll try to make an attempt at it.  Although I'm not very versed in Python.

Answer (score -1):

`hg help forget` and **don't forget** add this file to the ignore-list

Comment: Actually I did RTFM and while it says 'it does not delete them from the working directory' it absolutely does.  I just tested it in my environment by running 'hg forget' on the file in question on the main repository.  When I next did a pull and an update, the file was gone from my working directory.

Unless I'm missing something.  I don't see any options in hg help forget that suggests 'don't propagate deletion'